# Расчет угла с учетом расположения начала отрезка

Tags: python-3.x

Необходимо рассчитать угол наклона отрезка, но с учетом расположения начала и конца.

```
import math

trox = float(3.0)
troy = float(3.0)

rxox = float(7.0)
rxoy = float(5.0)

len_line = math.sqrt(((rxox-trox)**2)+((rxoy-troy)**2))
print('%.3f' % len_line)
angel = math.degrees(math.atan((rxoy-troy)/(rxox-trox)))
print('%.3f' % angel)
```

В выше приведенном коде начало отрезка ниже и левее чем конец. Потому угол составляет 26 градусов. Вроде все понятно. Но если поменять местами начало и конец отрезка, то значение угла будет точно таким же. А мне необходимо учитывать направление отрезка вокруг его начала. Теоретически значение угла должно быть 206 градусов. Как реализовать это?

Comment: Всё правильно, арктангенс изменяется от -pi/2 до pi/2

Comment: Дак как быть то?

Answer (score 1):

```
angel = math.degrees(math.atan2(rxoy-troy))
```

---

> я уже пробовал так. Не подходит. Все равно считает 26 градусов.

Вы хотите сказать, что две строчки

```
print math.degrees(math.atan2(1,1))
print math.degrees(math.atan2(-1,-1))
```

выводят два одинаковых числа?

Comment: я уже пробовал так. Не подходит. Все равно считает 26 градусов.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что арктангенс не различает такие случаи. Ведь `tg(x) == tg(x + pi)`. Поэтому арктангенс в обоих случаях получается одинаковый, причём в пределах от -pi/2 до pi/2.
Добавляйте к углу `math.pi`, если отрезок начинается правее своего конца.

```
angel = math.atan((rxoy-troy)/(rxox-trox))
x1 = rxox  # начало
x2 = trox  # конец
if x1 > x2:
    angel += math.pi
angel = math.degrees(angel)
print('%.3f' % angel)
```

P.S. Можно добавлять не `math.pi` к радианам, а 180 к градусам.

Чтобы получить угол в отрезке [0; 2*pi], можно сделать так

для радиан:

```
angel %= 2*math.pi
```

или для градусов:

```
angel %= 360
```

Comment: Тоже думал в таком направлении, но думаю что кроме значений по оси 0Х нужно учитывать и значения по 0У.

Comment: @Rashid-s, нет, это будет работать всегда.

Comment: попробуйте сами.                                                                                                                              
     trox = float(3.0)
     troy = float(3.0)
     
     rxox = float(7.0)
     rxoy = float(1.0)  Получится 153 градуса, а должно по идее 334

Comment: @Rashid-s, и что вас смущает? Угол между положительным направлением Ox и вектором 153.435 градуса. Необязательно писать везде float().

Comment: @Rashid-s, в моём примере вектор начинается в rxox, заканчивается в trox. Там угол 153.435. Если смотреть наоборот, получается -26.565. Если вам нужен угол в [0; 2pi], делайте в конце так: angel %= 360